# Category of vector bundles over a space is additive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

Consider the category of vector bundles over a fixed base space. Then this category is not abelian, since the kernel of a morphism of bundles is in general not a vector bundle. But is it additive? What would be the zero object? Is the product the fiber product?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the rank of your vector bundles fixed?

Comment: Have you looked into K-theory?

Comment: @Mauro Porta. No, the rank is not fixed.

Comment: @Neal. No I have never looked into K-theory. How is it useful?

Comment: There is a related MO discussion you may find interesting at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107101/is-the-category-of-vector-bundles-over-a-topological-space-abelian.

Comment: @Ferenc I don't know it well, but the idea is to explore the ring of (suitable equivalence classes of) vector bundles over a fixed (compact Hausdorff) base.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_K-theory

Comment: The zero object is the trivial bundle $M \times \{ 0 \}$, of course, and the direct sum is the fibre product (Whitney sum).

Comment: @Zhen. Thank you, that is what I thought, but the definition of zero object that I have seen is not really intuitive.

Comment: @Neil. Thank you it seems very interesting!

Comment: A zero object is an object $Z$ such that for every object $X$ there is a unique morphism $X \to Z$ and a unique morphism $Z \to X$. What could be simpler?

Answer (score 4):

If the base $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then the topological [Serre-Swan theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem) asserts that the category of vector bundles over $X$ is equivalent to the category of finitely-generated projective modules over $C(X)$. This naturally sits in the abelian category of all modules over $C(X)$ as an additive subcategory.

In general the category of vector bundles over $X$ should sit naturally in the abelian category of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on $X$ as an additive subcategory (or something like that; I don't know much about sheaf theory).